# Detecting a rising edge in a digitized microphone signal

Tags: algorithm, signals, signal-processing

I am working on a algorithm to detect a pattern as shown in the image. Black is the signal , red one is the pattern I want to detect. I tried calculating the slope (with tolerance) and detecting if the pattern is matched. Are there any other algorithms/methods to detect these kind of shapes ?
Any inputs much appreciated!!

Algorithm tried so far.

PEAK - Max signal value before which I must generate the trigger.

MIN_THRESHOLD - lowest value of the signal for which the algortihm starts calculating the slopes.

```
for all the samples 

    if(signal(i) <= PEAK and signal(i) >= MIN_THRESHOLD)

        current_slope_array(k) = (signal(i) - signal(i-1) ) / sampling_time
        k++; i++;
    end if

loop

slope_average = average(current_slope_array)
```

[image: Image source]

Comment: what image? are you detecting on images or the data which is generating the image? if its images, opencv is a good place to look

Comment: its not an image. its a signal, like voice samples from a microphone.. I am looking to generate a trigger when I see that kind of a rising edge. So far , the slope method has not worked very well..

Comment: could you expand your question to include what form the data is in, and how you tried to calculate the slope

Comment: your way of computing an average slope is not very stable, usually one would compute an average slope from more distant points. Anyway, I think there are better approaches. But therefore we would need to know more about your problem. Is it a real time problem, where the signal comes in value by value and you have to react immediately? Or do you know the whole signal in advance and just want to find peaks?

Comment: @coproc this is real time analysis. not offline.

Comment: Please specify how often you expect your rising edges and how much variability in height and width you expect. Without this information, the question is simply too broad.

Answer (score 1):

This is very classical signal processing. I think reading a bit up on basics of signal processing would help here, so I'll link you to GNU Radio's [page of suggested literature](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/SuggestedReading#Digital_Signal_Processing).

Usually, microphone signals digitize *sound*; Sound usually contains harmonic *oscillations*, which occur at a given *frequency*; the length of your slope directly relates to the frequency you're looking for. Designing a band pass filter will eliminate signals that don't relate to the slopes you're looking for (especially a lot of noise!). Having strongly filtered your signal, you can decimate it, which will (by what is called *aliasing*) move your band pass region to *baseband* (ie. close to 0 Hz).

You can then simply estimate the *phase* of your signal.

I'm sorry I can't put that much easier, but this is signal processing, which is a engineering discipline which lets you build optimal estimators for a lot of things, but you have to be able to describe the things you want to detect mathematically. Without the basics of signal processing, though, your ability to mathematically understand what you're trying to do will lack, and hence I can only offer you the key words (which I *highlighted* above), which should lead you through your learning process.

Comment: The problem is not yet clear to me. For example the rising edge does not have to come periodically and then a spectral approach might fail.

Comment: @Trilarion: that would be impossible for a signal that comes from a soundcard, as these are low pass filtered, ie. for every rise there must be a fall.

Comment: New link: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/SuggestedReading

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify your problem enough (characteristics of the signal, characteristics of the parts you want to have) to allow for a clean answer.

So I just propose a [constant fraction discriminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_fraction_discriminator) which is one of the many strategies to detect rising edges.

In short: Split the signal in two, invert one and delay it by the rising edge width, then add them together both and watch for zero crossings.